# Find out information about PerformanceCounter

Tags: c#, .net, windows, performance, monitoring

I am trying to use [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve some performance details on Windows. I have used [PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a65ekyd.aspx) method and run the sample code from the link which gives all the category names available on the machine it's run on.

I have run code from [BlackWasp.co.uk](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ReadPerformanceCounters.aspx) which demonstrates how to use PerformanceCounter with example code.

What I am missing, is that the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0wssx8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes at minimum two strings as arguments, counterCategory and counterName. I can get the counter categories from PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories but how do I set the names?

I understand from this I should set the names using [PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs38wsc4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but how do I tie that to a specified behaviour I am trying to monitor, such as disk reads, etc.?

The sample code is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Creating Inventory custom counter");
if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("Inventory"))
    PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("Inventory",
        "Truck inventory",
        PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance,
        "Trucks", "Number of trucks on hand");
```

This sort of leaves me in the dark as I have no idea where "Truck Inventory" or "Trucks" come from.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is there a better way to do performance monitoring?

So how do I create a performance counter and tie it to meaningful hardware performance?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37b8b63a-da32-4497-b570-3811a2255dee/how-to-get-disk-io-countersdisk-write-time-disk-read-time-using-cnet?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Performance counters have to be registered first.  And there needs to be *some* kind of app that sets their value.  Only then can you expect to be able to read such a counter.  Your question gives no hint at all that you took care of those preliminary steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233084/438322) (explained below) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1305159) if you want to do it programmatically.

Essentially if you need to find out what Performance Counters you can access go -

**Start -> Search box -> perfmon**

Click on perfmon.exe. This will get you a window. Click

**Monitoring Tools -> Performance Monitor**

This will give you a graph. Right click on the graph and click **Add Counters**

This gives you a list of all the possible Counter Categories. Click the arrow on the left of the list of Categories and a list of all possible Names and Instances will appear.

This covers the two main constructors of PerformanceCounter:

```
PerformanceCounter(string counterCategory, string counterName)
PerformanceCounter(string counterCategory, string counterName, string counterInstance)
```

Also, if you are a total newbie to this topic like I was, it might be useful for you to know this has to be tied to a timer (generally speaking) as it takes the measurement from the last interval.

Here is a bare bones console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace Performance
{
    class PerformanceTest
    {
        PerformanceCounter memory;

        Timer timer;

        public PerformanceTest()
        {
            memory = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
            // Get a new value every 10 seconds
            timer = new Timer(PerformanceTimer_Tick, null, 0, 10000);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            PerformanceTest pt = new PerformanceTest();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void PerformanceTimer_Tick(object sender)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Memory Available: " + memory.NextValue().ToString() + "\n");
            // Force garbage collection
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```